# How to use TPerlRegex with Unicode

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

How can I use TPerRegex with regular Delphi `String` type avoiding any UTF-8 <> UTF-16 string conversions. It seems Delphi XE5 doesn't come with UTF-16 capable PCRE library?

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=108941

As of version 8.30 PCRE supports Unicode.

Comment: The linked report is resolved. Anyone know the resolution?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The solution is to use `TJclWideRegEx` which has UTF-16 implementation of `PCRE`. Thankfully no need to wait for Embarcadero. Plus it works in FPC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `JclPCRE` and statically link `PCRE` with it.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK PCRE library embedded with Delphi is not compiled with UTF-16 APIs, but with UTF-8 APIs.

But *once again*, UTF-8 is as Unicode-ready as UTF-16! So the PCRE version embedded within Delphi XE5 is 100% Unicode ready... :)

Your link states in addition that [current implementation is dead slow](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=495830) due to wrong flags: `PCRE_NO_UTF8_CHECK` is missing in EMB's code.

You can try to use directly the lib [as we did here](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/05/24/REGEXP-operator-for-SQLite3), and by-pass the slow `TPerlRegEx` class.

The slowdown does not comes from the fact that the UTF-8 version of the library is used. UTF-8 version is as fast as the UTF-16 version. Nor is the UTF-16 into UTF-8 conversion slow by itself: it will just be a slightly slowdown. But the issue is this missing `PCRE_NO_UTF8_CHECK` flag...

Comment: Yes but this isn't version 8.30. Plus I cannot use it on Chinese text, can I?

Comment: @user Do you want to use it with special non-Unicode Chinese text? Do you understand the UTF-8 and UTF-16 are complete Unicode encodings?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No. I have a chinese text and I want to use Regex on it. Simple isn't it? I guess I need another library.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is `TPerlRegex` in Delphi XE5 version 8.30? If not then its not Unicode ready. Period.

Comment: You can of course use UTF-8 to process Chinese text, with no issue. Library version 8.30 is Unicode ready, via UTF-8 APIs. AFAIK the library is compiled with `SUPPORT_UTF8` conditional, so *does support Unicode* [as stated by official PCRE web site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html). I guess you made a confusion between `SUPPORT_UTF8` and `PCRE_NO_UTF8_CHECK`.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Sorry but there is also `SUPPORT_UTF16`. Thankfully there is full `UTF-16` in JclPCRE..

Comment: @user It looks like you don't know what Unicode is. It is not the same as UTF-16. That is but one of many Unicode encodings.